# Why Scalar Multiplication is not commutative/Abelian?

Tags: linear-algebra, abelian-groups

Definition 2.9 (Vector Space). A real-valued vector space V = (V,+, ·) is vector space
a set V with two operations

- : V × V → V (2.62)
  · : R × V → V (2.63)
  where

1. (V, +) is an Abelian group

Source: Mathematics for Machine Learning

Question: Why (V,.) is not an Abelian group? Scalar multiplication of a vector is commutative. Please help me understand this part.

Comment: Scalar multiplication is not a binary operation on $V$ unless $V = R$ (when it is indeed commutative). I expect that the first notation (for a map $V \times V \to V$) is intended to be $+$ (for the addition of $V$) and not $\cdot$. The multiplication  on $R$ is not a group operation because there is no inverse element for $0$. For clarity it might help to reproduce "2.62" and "2.63" exactly as in the text

Answer (score 2):

$V$ under scalar multiplication alone does not make sense for a group; there are other aspects to the definition of "abelian group" you're overlooking, and commutativity is not the only item of concern.

A group is a pair $(G,\ast)$, where $\ast$ is an operation that satisfies certain conditions. In particular, it is a function $\ast : G \times G \to G$.

Suppose $V$ is a vector space over the field $F$. Then the mapping of scalar multiplication is instead a function $F \times V \to V$: it sends a scalar and a vector to a vector; it does not send pairs of vectors to other vectors (unlike the addition of vectors).

> ***Note:*** There are a scant few circumstances where this argument is incomplete; for instance, a field is a vector space over itself, with a very natural definition for scalar multiplication. For instance, $\mathbb{R}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, and so one could naively think that (scalar) multiplication is a permissible operation. However, we then encounter the issue that, since $0 \in \mathbb{R}$ (and we need this for it to be a vector space and a field), there is an element with no inverse under multiplication in $\mathbb{R}$, namely $0$ itself. This logic holds more broadly in other fields as well.